# 3 steps to find one of 12 balls

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine you have 12 balls. They are all the same color. We know that one ball is different in weight from the others but we dont know is it heavier or easier. You have a beam scale without measurements on it. Just two sides where you can put any number of balls on it. In three steps find the ball that is different in weight from other balls.

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/pool_balls.html

Comment: wow. this was really fast...:) thanks.

Comment: Yes. I see. Thanks.